# ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous: x sizes: 3 y sizes: 13 Make sure all arrays contain the same number of samples

Tags: python, tensorflow

Can someone explain this error to me? I don't understand why my output layer is "ambiguous". The problem is the data I'm trying to train on is fed to me from a game's API, so I can't provide the data off-hand and the output is only my "desired output".

```
self.data_inputs = np.array([[self.car_location], [self.car_velocity], [self.ball_location]]).astype(np.float)
self.data_outputs = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]).astype(np.float)
tmp_model = population[i]
tmp_model.fit(self.data_inputs, self.data_outputs, epochs=150, batch_size=32, verbose=0)
move_to_make = tmp_model.predict(self.data_inputs)
fitness_score = np.asarray(self.fitness(move_to_make))
```